# How to find files which I open the most?

Tags: macos, search, file-management, metadata

Is there a way to figure out which files I open most often on my computer? For example, a simple count of how many times a file has been opened in the past N days would be a good start. Finding a way to sort files according to this number is the next step. I have no idea if this metadata is tracked at all.

I am using MacOS, but I'll leave this open-ended so answers for non-Mac systems are acceptable. But of course, I am hoping for a Mac answer.

Comment: It might be possible, because macOS definitely records a last opened timestamp, on the file itself, but whether it logs that anywhere even semi-permanently, like Console… your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of times a file/directory has been opened?](https://superuser.com/questions/844560/how-to-count-the-number-of-times-a-file-directory-has-been-opened)

Comment: @treedust The `auditd` and the OpenBSM framework are "deprecated" by Apple.  Is there a replacement?